# I want to auto download Chrome.exe file into my currrent project directory using Webdriver manager in Robot framework

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, webdrivermanager-python

Currently I'm downloading exe files manually and using for browser launch in Python Robot framework. I just want to upgrade it auto download using Webdriver Manager.

I tried below code but its downloaded and save it the path we configured in pip list [2nd line of code]. Instead of auto download in my local machine, I want to download directly into project directory because of few restriction issues in my organisation. Can anyone provide suggestions on this?

```
pip install webdrivermanager

webdrivermanager firefox chrome --linkpath /usr/local/bin

from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

def get_chromedriver_path():
    driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    print(driver_path)
    return  driver_path

Library  chromedriversync.py

${chromedriver_path}=   chromedriversync.Get Chromedriver Path
Create Webdriver    chrome   executable_path=${chromedriver_path}
Go to  www.google.com
```

Comment: Is all of the code in that code block in a single file? If not, please attempt to fix the formatting so that it's clear what code is in what file.

Comment: Tanks for your reply @BryanOakley and below code work out for me!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto download .exe files to project directory based on browser version using Webdriver Manager in Python Robotframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912715/how-to-auto-download-exe-files-to-project-directory-based-on-browser-version-us)

Answer (score 0):

To download .exe files into current project directory, we can use os library as below, below code worked out as per requirement. Adding for other's reference,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from lib2to3.tests.support import driver
import os
from os.path import curdir

def get_chromedriver_path():
    ReturnPath = os.getcwd()
    driver_path = ChromeDriverManager(path=ReturnPath).install()
    print(driver_path)
    return driver_path

   
Library    browser.py

    ${driver}=    browser.Get Chromedriver Path
    log    ${driver}  
    Create Webdriver    Chrome    executable_path=${driver}    chrome_options=${options}
```